# How to remove steps from checkout in Sylius

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sylius

I'm using `sylius/sylius` 1.3.9 with `symfony/framework-bundle` 4.2.4.  Regarding the [doc](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/cookbook/shop/checkout.html#how-to-remove-a-step-from-checkout) to remove states from checkout you have to replace the whole configuration of the Sylius core bundle.

I put my configuration into `src/Resources/SyliusCoreBundle/config/app/state_machine/sylius_order_checkout.yml`:

```
winzou_state_machine:
    sylius_order_checkout:
        class: '%sylius.model.order.class%'
        property_path: checkoutState
        graph: sylius_order_checkout
        state_machine_class: '%sylius.state_machine.class%'
        states:
            cart: ~
            addressed: ~
            completed: ~
        transitions:
            address:
                from: [cart, addressed]
                to: addressed
            complete:
                from: [addressed]
                to: completed
        callbacks:
            after:
                sylius_process_cart:
                    on: [address]
                    do: ['@sylius.order_processing.order_processor', process]
                    args: [object]
                sylius_create_order:
                    on: [complete]
                    do: ['@sm.callback.cascade_transition', apply]
                    args: [object, event, create, sylius_order]
                sylius_save_checkout_completion_date:
                    on: [complete]
                    do: [object, completeCheckout]
                    args: [object]
```

After that I execute:

```
php bin/console cache:clear -e dev
[...]
php bin/console debug:winzou:state-machine sylius_order_checkout -e dev

+--------------------+
| Configured States: |
+--------------------+
| cart               |
| addressed          |
| shipping_selected  |
| shipping_skipped   |
| payment_skipped    |
| payment_selected   |
| completed          |
+--------------------+
[...]
```

Nothing changed. When I follow the [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc) in the doc it says:

> Bundle inheritance was removed in Symfony 4.0 [...]

So is it still possible with Symfony 4.2 to replace a whole configuration file of a bundle like suggested by the docs or is this a regression in Sylius 1.3 and what would be a possible solution if I did nothing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create `state_machine` directory in `config/packages`, put your YAML file and add this line in `configureContainer()` method into src/Kernel:

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        ...
        $loader->load($confDir.'/state_machine/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }
```

Comment: I have added this in config/state_machine/state_machine.yml and deleted all callbacks: after: steps, transitions and states but still the checkout process goes about it's normal business. If I put the file in config/packages/state_machine/ it tells me it can't find it, under config/state_machine/ no such message, but also no effect. Any idea? Thank you in advance!